# Problem with horizontal grey/gray bar when editing files in Eclipse 2019-09+

Tags: eclipse, editing

[image]Specs: Linux Mint 18.3, Java 11.

I am currently using Eclipse 2019-06.  I just tried upgrading to 2019-12 (or 2019-09).

With both these newer versions a strange problem occurs: when editing any kinds of files (Groovy, Java, Python, etc.), I find that as soon as I start typing a stupid horizontal grey bar appears in the line, hiding the text in the line completely, meaning that I can't see what I'm typing!

By doing some installations of 2019-06, 2019-09 and 2019-12 I am about 99.5% sure that this problem first crops up with 2019-09.

***edit***

As requested, here is a screenshot. This is a completely fresh install with no plug-ins: there happen to be some Groovy projects in this workspace, but I have not installed Groovy-Eclipse.

I get this same problem with Groovy, Java and Python files, suggesting it is Eclipse-related. I don't get anything like this in Eclipse 2019-06.

What actually happens: basically the instant I put the cursor on a line the entire line gets this grey bar, obscuring any text. When I start typing it does not go away. So it makes it basically impossible to edit.

I have tried installing 2019-09 and 2019-12 several times: this problem always occurs.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you talking about. Do you have additional plug-ins installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can turn this off at Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Highlight current line